# How do I break a line with :substitute?

Tags: substitute

I usually have to worry about escaping *search* parameters to get special characters to match literally, but this time I'm seeing a problem with my replacement string.

I want to take text like this:

```
@@ something @@ should_be_on_another_line
```

And turn it into this:

```
@@ something @@
 should_be_on_another_line
```

`/ @@ /` matches the second `@@` pair on each line just fine, but when I try this command:

`:%s/ @@ / @@ \n/g`

I actually end up with this:

`@@ something @@^@ should_be_on_another_line`

I tried escaping the `@@ \n` in the replacement as `\@\@ \n`, but that didn't help (same results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  The newline should be `\r` in your substitute command.

Try

```
:%s/ @@ / @@ \r /g
```

from `:help :%s`

```
  <CR>        split line in two at this point
              (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)                  s<CR>
  \r          idem                                               s/\r
  \<CR>       insert a carriage-return (CTRL-M)
              (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)                  s/\<CR>
  \n          insert a <NL> (<NUL> in the file)
              (does NOT break the line)                          s/\n
```

**EDIT**: The issue is not about escaping the `@` in your substitute command.  The meaning of `\n` differs between the **search** or the **replace** side of the expression. The `\n` on the right side of the  expression inserts `^@`.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/350661/5978252) has more details, in particular: `:h s/\n` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/350798/5978252)

---

Comment: Thanks; although I must say I'm not sure how that documentation explains any of this. \r is carriage return (aka <CR>) and \n is line feed (aka new line). I get that they would match different things, but shouldn't I be able to replace with either of them (and get different results)?

Comment: Simplified: `:%s/ @@ /&\r/g`. See `:h :s%` for more information.