# Insert newline (\n) at search and replace but get "^@" instead

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I want to set a linebreak after all braces `}`.

I tried to replace the braces by newline `\n` with:

```
:%s/\}/\n/
```

But all I got is a `^@` instead of a new line.

Example:

```txt
abc{def} foo bar{baz} and so on
```

I expected to get

```txt
abc{def
 foo bar{baz
 and so on
```

But then I had

```txt
abc{def^@ foo bar{baz^@ and so on
```

(VIM v. 8.0.1453, ubuntu)

Comment: You need to use either `::%s/\}/\r/` or `:%s/\}/^M/` where `^M` is actually typed with `ctrl+v` `<CR>`. We have a duplicate of this question which I'm trying to find.

Comment: `::%s/\}/\r/` works fine (`^M` does not, then I get "`<cr>`"). But why `\r`...? Whatever. Thank you very much. It woud be nice to link my question or answere it with your comment. :)

Comment: Inserting `<CR>` literally with  [`:h i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V) should work, you might not be using it properly. For why `\r` see this https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9386

Comment: @statox title needs edited, but perhaps this (one such) dupe? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12965/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I couldn't find a better one so yes this would would probably work as a dupe :)