# Replacement of characters gives ^@ when replaced with newline but not newline

Tags: neovim, gvim, substitute, insert-mode, replace

Why does replacement of something by using `:%s/,/\n/gc` in vim gives me ^@ instead of giving me newline. Sed replacement works perfectly `sed s/,/'\n'/g`. Any idea how to do sed thingy in Vim and save time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12965/10604

Comment: ye it does answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because a line break in the replacement component of the substitution command is represented by `\r` in Vim rather than `\n`...

```
:s/,/\r/gc
```

Alernatively, you can use this:

```
:s/,/^M/gc
```

Where the `^M` is entered by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

See [`:h s/\r`](http://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s%2F%5Cr) and  [`:h s/<CR>`](http://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s%3CCR%3E)

FYI using `\n` will...

> insert a `<NL>` (`<NUL>` in the file) (does NOT break the line)

...to quote [`:h s/\n`](http://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s%2F%5Cn)